# How to keep state property's value beyond component's parent updates with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new with react hooks and i'm using a functional component in which the state holds a certain property 'view':

```
const [view, setView] = useState();
```

The good thing with react hooks is to keep the property's value beyond the component state updates but why it can't keep it also when the component's parent renders due to its own state update ?

Is it possible somehow to keep it in such as case with any react hooks ?

Comment: Rendering a parent component shouldn't affect the state of a child component, unless you're unmounting that child. Can you show us how the parent is rendering this child so we can see if you're unmounting it?

Comment: After i tried to reproduce my app in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/red-monad-7j2op?file=/src/TinyEditor.js, i understood that the difference is that i'm using react-router-dom routing which probably causes the unmount. I dont think it is possible to keep my component's state props values even after an unmount. But in the same time , when i update the parent component it's not a route change i think so i wonder why it happens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the child value when the parent value is updated then you can simulate 'watching' it with useEffect.

If the parent is passing down a prop let's say 'valueFromParent'
inside the child you can do

```
useEffect(() => { setView(valueFromParent)}, props.valueFromParent)
```